# Ionic: Location tracking not working in background while using cordova-plugin-geolocation

Tags: geolocation, ionic3, cordova-plugins, background-process

I am trying to build an android app to track vehicles using the driver's phone. When the driver receives a call or minimizes the app on an android phone, the phone goes into background mode. When background mode is activated I want the device to keep collecting location data and sending it to my server. I use a watch (watchPosition) to collect position data. Once the app goes into the background, watchPosition doesn't seem to return any position. Does watchPosition work in background mode? Is geolocation possible in background mode? Any suggestions on how to solve this problem.The flow starts when startTracking() is called.

```
startTracking() {
console.log('Gonna Start Tracking');
if (!(this.activeTelematicData && this.activeTelematicData.imei)) {
  alert("Invalid Telematic Data. Please contact support.");
  return undefined;
}

this.active = true;
this.watchAndSendLocationData();
this.backgroundMode.enable();
this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(() => {
  console.log("background mode set.");
  this.watchAndSendLocationData();
});
// this.collectAndSendLocationData();
// this.process = setInterval(this.collectAndSendLocationData, 10000);}

watchAndSendLocationData() {
this.process = this.geolocation.watchPosition(this.geolocationOptions);
this.process
  // .filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined) //Filter Out Errors
  .subscribe((position) => {
    if (this.active && position && position.coords && position.timestamp) {
      this.sendLocationData(position);
    } else if (this.active) {
      // alert("Position empty: " + JSON.stringify(position.timestamp) + ". Please contact support.");
    }
  }, (error) => {
    alert("Get Location Error message: " + error.message);
    alert("Get Location Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });}
```

P.S. The backgroundMode.on("activate") works on activation as the log statement is received. I do know that there are additional Cordova plugins that solve background geolocation directly but I am trying to solve it using this plugin for some really specific reason.